# Preventing button action again,while the action is performing

Tags: java

In java when a button action is executed how to prevent the same button to be clicked again during the execution.

Comment: A very simple approach is to disable the button immediately after a click, and re-enable it after the action is complete. This will solve many problems which happen due to double-clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button after cliking it with the method setEnabled(false), and enable the button again when the action is done with setEnabled(true).